# Dynamic id in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-filter

```
$("#someId_"+someName).css(....);
```

This is what i am doing to get the div in jquery.
This is working just fine except when 'someName' contains String with multiple tokens
like "Mohammad Adil"

is there any other way of doing the same thing ?

thanks..

Comment: Your selector points to the fact that you're using an ID selector. "Multiple tokens" refers to spaces and that pretty much is a no go for element ids.

Comment: I thought you were looking for getting a number ID, you have problem with spaces inside the ID?

Comment: In reference to what f0x is saying: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: @Jose: Did you even read the question?

Comment: @Rocket: as I said, I (mis)read and already flagged my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do that. You cannot have spaces in your `id`.

Quoting the [HTML5 spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-id-attribute)(*emphasis mine*)

> The id attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID). The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character. **The value must not contain any space characters.**

Answer (score 3):

You can't have spaces in ID's so you would have to convert it to a dash or something that is valid.
`someName.Replace(" ","-")` is the code to convert the space to a dash.

If this doesn't help then please explain some more. is someName a list of names or is it a single name that needs to be an ID?

Comment: someName is a  single name that needs to be an id with a prefix.

Comment: Then you will have to make spaces dashes or something like that. ID's cannot have a space

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have spaces in your `ID`s, but there is a way to select the div anyway.

```
$("[id='someId_"+someName+"']")
```

I suggest instead of spaces, you use something else, like an underscore.

```
<div id="someId_Mohammad_Adil"></div>
```

Then your `$("#someId_"+someName)` will work (as long as `someName` has the spaces converted to underscores: `someName = someName.replace(' ', '_');`)